# How to deal with sparse arrays and undefined in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, undefined

I currently have a sparse array with "holes". Consider:

```
let arr: number[] = []
arr[2] = 5

// arr = [,,5]
```

I am looking up indices in the array using a second array like so:

```
let indices: number[] = [1, 2]
console.log(
  indices.map(i => arr[i])
    .includes(undefined)
)
// Expected output: true
```

However, I get this error: `Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.`

I think this is because Typescript thinks that `arr` can only contain numbers, while in reality the "holes" in the array evaluate to `undefined`. Even though `arr[1] === undefined`.

I can use a union type of `number | undefined` to get around this, but is there a better way?

Having come from Javascript, I'm still relatively new to Typescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't know how to deal with sparse arrays because [it doesn't acknowledge their existence](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49913#issuecomment-1184967414).

From what I've found though, it seems like the way to deal with this is probably to just do what you suggested—type the array as `(number | undefined)[]`.

```typescript
const arr: (number | undefined)[] = []
arr[2] = 5
// arr = [,,5]

const indices: number[] = [1, 2]
console.log(indices.includes(undefined)) // true
```

If you have a lot of sparse arrays like this it's possible you would want a helper type `SparseArray<T>` (though it probably wouldn't be useful in most cases):

```typescript
type SparseArray<T> = (T | undefined)[]
const arr: SparseArray<number> = []
arr[2] = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `includes` you could use `some`

```
indices.map(i => arr[i]).some(x => x === undefined)
```

Comment: It's a nicer hack, but still a hack nonetheless. Is there a standard for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want all `Array` types to include `undefined` values, you can simply enable the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option ([example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjBcEB2BXAtgIxDA2gXQgF4J8AoWXAJgOIFZTTRIBLJAE2YGMQBnRVTNnxESARgA0EaqU4B7JD1mgAdMFkBzABSkIEVh249laKAAdNzIgD5ocHMzwBKHbojLWnYCja9NKdiAAZqwgbM6OQA)).

**Warning:** Since this makes type checking more strict by requiring type guards or assertions around collection values, you may get additional TypeScript errors.